# Fastest way to select first child of element type jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup for custom style checkboxes:

```
<div class="btn-custom-checkbox-container" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: left;">
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" id="cantAttend<?php echo $n; ?> onclick="this.blur();" class="btn customCheckbox cantAttendCheckboxButton">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked checkboxView"></span>
            I cannot attend this conference
        </button>
        <input id="" type="checkbox" class="hidden cantAttendCheckbox" title="">
     </span>
</div>
```

And I have this as the jQuery to control toggling the glyphicons on the `span` to show whether or not the checkbox is ticked:

```
$(".customCheckbox").click(function () {
    $(this).find("span").first().toggleClass('glyphicon-check glyphicon-unchecked');
});
```

Is this the fastest way to the select the necessary span? There are like a million different ways to select it, but I want a clear answer as to what the 'best' way is...

Comment: I would use `$(this).find("span.glyphicon:first")`

Comment: @Satpal I don't think it would be 'faster'

Comment: You don't really need to optimze it because anyway it would select element still faster than you could click its parent. But the fastest way should be to use: `$(this).children(':first-child').toggleClass(...);`

Answer (score 0):

try below code for fast selection

```html
$(".customCheckbox > span ").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-check glyphicon-unchecked');
});
```

Comment: But you bind click event only to span, not the whole button

Comment: Yeah this will require me to click the `span` as opposed to the button as a whole